# mvc4 modelstate check what is wrong

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate

I have some code in my HTTP action method and also a modelstate to make sure that everything is valid; when I put the modelstate my code does not execute and goes directly to the redirect

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(profile).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.success = "Your changes have been saved";
                return View(new article_detail() { profile = profile });
            }
               return RedirectToAction("edit");
```

Is there a method that I can use to findout what field in my model is causing the **ModelState** to not pass? Typically the way I do it is to do a breakpoint and then look over each field to see what's going on but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way ..any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line at the beginning of your controller action and activate a breakpoint on it:

```
var modelStateErrors = ModelState
    .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
    .ToArray();
```

When your controller action is invoked and the breakpoint is hit, press <kbd>F10</kbd> and inspect the value of the `modelStateErrors` variable. It will probably help you know which field you forgot to POST in order to make your model valid.